# Print data of a function in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have defined the following function. The output was fine as well. Is it possible to print the return value after using the function?

```
def runningMeanFast(x, N):
    return np.convolve(x, np.ones((N,))/N)[(N-1):]

plt.figure(8)
plt.title('Sigupper vs time fitting')
#plot(time,SigUpper,'-r',label='Data')
plot(time[time_fit],runningMeanFast(SigUpper[time_fit],5),'b',label='convolution')
plt.grid()
xlabel(r'time')
ylabel(r'z/d')
#plt.ylim(1.5,6)
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
savefig('8.png')
```

Comment: You indentation makes no sense. You immediately return something after entering the function, then you make some operations outside of the function, but not at the right level.You are neither inside of the function, nor outside.

Comment: Of course, put the line `print('data')` after the line where you are calling the function. (In other words, I have no idea what your exact question is.)

Comment: What do you mean by data? The return value of the function? If yes, simply save the value in a variable and pass the variable to plot. Afterwards you can simply use print on the variable.

Comment: Yes the return value of the function. I have edited the indentation in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an intermediary step to print the result:

```
def runningMeanFast(x, N):
    result = np.convolve(x, np.ones((N,))/N)[(N-1):]
    print(result)
    return result
```

This will print the data, and **then** return it.

If you want to return the data **then** print it, then you should store the returned value, and print it after all your processing:

```
data = runningMeanFast(SigUpper[time_fit], 5)
plot(time[time_fit], data, 'b', label='convolution')
# Processing...
print(data)
```